# Is there a way to prevent spreadsheet from updating the date to today's date in formula?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to print the date when I change the value on a cell (status column). But `spreadsheets` update the date to today's date. I wish it could save the date from when the status was changed.

The code to print the date:

```
function TIMESTAMP() {

  var today = new Date();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(today, 'GMT-3', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  return date;

}
```

In the spreadsheet, the column `D` is where I set the status and columns `H` to `J` print the date from when the status was changed.

[image: Spreadsheet]

The code for column `H` is the following:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(H:H)=1;"Logística";IF(ISBLANK(D:D);;IF((D:D>=3)*(D:D<6);TIMESTAMP();IF(D:D<1;"Aguardando Pagamento";IF(D:D=2;"Aguardando Etiqueta";IF(D:D=6;"Cancelado";"Aguardando Faturamento")))))))
```

The codes for columns `I` and `J` are similar to `H`. So, how to print the date from when the status in column `D` was changed and keep `spreadsheet` from updating to today's date?

Comment: How does the data on the spreadsheet get updated?

Comment: If I manually change the value on cells on column D, or when I open the spreadsheet on the next day, the dates from yesterday become the dates of today.

Comment: What I'm asking is: Is the column D manually updated? or is it updated automatically using Apps Script?

Comment: The column D is updated manually.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but how about this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet Name' && e.range.columnStart == 4 ){
    let dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-3', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
    e.range.offset(0,4).setValue(dt)
  }
}
```

You have to change the sheet name

Comment: It doesn't work. It returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheet' of undefined (line 2)."

Comment: You can't run it from the script editor unless you provide the event object.

Comment: I ran it on spreadsheets to test if the code was functional, but it returned that error.

Comment: I just tested it on a spreadsheet and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Since you manually change the state on column `D`, you may use an `onEdit(e)` trigger to override the formula with the value that you want:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const { range } = e
  const sheet = range.getSheet()
  if(sheet.getName() === 'Set your sheet name here' && range.getColumn() <= 4 && range.getLastColumn() >= 4){
    const firstRow = range.getRow()
    const values = sheet
      .getRange(range.getRow(), 4, range.getHeight(), 1)
      .getValues()
      .flat()
    
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      const value = values[i]
      if (!Number.isInteger(value) || value < 3 || value > 5) continue

      const row = firstRow + i
      const col = value - 3 + 8
      const targetRange = sheet.getRange(row, col)

      const todayStr = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
      targetRange.setValue(todayStr)
    }
  }
}
```

This code works even when setting multiple rows at the same time. Remember to set the name of your sheet and the timezone you are in.

### References

- [Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format) (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)
- [Class Range (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)